# How can I convert a number into an array of digits?

Tags: arrays, powershell

I'm trying to find a way to convert a number into an array of digits, similar to a character array, and still be able to perform mathematical operations on the array.

My first thought was to convert the number to a string, then to a character array, and then convert the array back to Int32 type. However, this has some unexpected results. For example, `[int[]](1024).ToString().ToCharArray()` results in the following array:

```
49
48
50
52
```

I do get what's happening here - PowerShell is treating the digits as ASCII characters, and converting them into their numeric values. However, that doesn't help me solve my problem.

What's the "right way" to convert numbers into single-digit integer arrays?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK.

```
[int[]][string[]][char[]]'1024'
([int[]][string[]][char[]]'1024').gettype()
1
0
2
4

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType                   
-------- -------- ----                                     --------                   
True     True     Int32[]                                  System.Array
```

Starting with 1024, cast it to [char[]] to separate the digits. Then cast the chars to string to make the int conversion literal text, rather than ascii code.

Different tack, starting with [int], and minimizing casts:

```
$n = 1024
$array = [int[]](($n -split '') -ne '')

$array
$array.GetType()


1
0
2
4

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType                   
-------- -------- ----                                     --------                   
True     True     Int32[]                                  System.Array
```

Comment: This works if your number is already a string. Is there a way to do it if it's an integer, preferably *without* having to do *another* conversion into a string?

Comment: Posted another version

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
[char[]]'1024' | %{$_ - 48}
```

This will convert the characters to ints of the correct value:

```
C:\PS> [char[]]'1024' | %{$_ - 48} | %{$_.GetType().Name}
Int32
Int32
Int32
Int32
```

Here is a "mathy" version that works with an int:

```
C:\PS> $number = 1024
C:\PS> $numDigits = [math]::Floor([math]::Log10($number)) + 1
C:\PS> $res = @()
C:\PS> for ($i = 0; $i -lt $numDigits; $i++) {$res += $number % 10; $number = [Math]::Floor($number / 10)}
C:\PS> $res[($res.count-1)..0]
1
0
2
4
```

Comment: Ah, so easy because the ASCII values are all 48 higher than the digit values. Not exactly "pure", but it works!

Comment: The other option is to use [Math]::Log10() to determine number of digits and then continuously take modulo 10 and divide by 10.